# Paradox query in SQL Assistant over ODBC - no column names

Tags: sql, paradox

I set up an ODBC connection to a paradox database, and I'm using Teradata SQL Assistant to query against the database.  However, no column names are being identified.  So, if I query:
SELECT TOP 1 FROM database, I get a record where every column name is "NoName"

column 2 is called "Date" in the paradox database.  I would like to be able to limit by query by that column.  How would I do this?

Comment: So, it requires that Paradox be installed locally, and then reboot the server.  It doesn't appear that the Paradox install modifies the driver, but something must change because now I get the column names.  I have tested this on multiple computers and I'm sure that the local install of Paradox is what causes the column names to now appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it requires that Paradox be installed locally, and then reboot the server. It doesn't appear that the Paradox install modifies the driver, but something must change because now I get the column names. I have tested this on multiple computers and I'm sure that the local install of Paradox is what causes the column names to now appear.  I installed the same version of Paradox as the database file I'm trying to access via ODBC over the network.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use AS otherName. That is: SELECT TOP 1 as myColumnName FROM database

Comment: I've tried to use "As otherName" for each of the columns, and all columns show the data from the first column.  So, I have a result set that shows the correct column names, but the data in each column is from column1.  SELECT TOP 1 NoName as Column1, NoName as Column2 FROM database

Comment: I don't know if you just wrote wrong. But it should be SELECT TOP 1 AS MyTop1Name, Column1 as MyOtherAltColumnName FROM database

Comment: That query gives a syntax error "the select statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect".    If I use "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM database", I get 1 record, with 11 columns called NoName.